# How to format import {} from '' as multiline?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

How do I un-join(?) or add trailing whitespace with indentation?

With this code,,,

```
import { amethod, methodb, methodc } from '../../utils/mockData';
```

how do you make this

```
import {
  amethod,
  methodb,
  methodc
} from '../../utils/mockData';
```

I mean how can I do it fast?

What I do is to

1. go to the first method.
2. press Enter
3. go to the end of the method..
4. press Enter...
5. go to the second method.
   6....
   ...

It's so slow with VIM. Can we do this fast in VIM?

Comment: Use `f<space>`. to jump to the spaces. Continue jumping using `;`. When you are on a space that you would like to be a linebreak, press `r<Enter>`. Continue

Comment: It worked... I continue to jump and make a line break

Comment: You can also use `.` to repeat the last change, and use it after the first `r<Enter>` -- so it becomes `;.` for the subsequent changes.

Answer (score 2):

Christian Brabandt has a good answer in the comments, and is similar to what I do in other situations: `f<Space>`, `r<Enter>`, then use `;.` to continue.

With tpope’s surround plugin, I can do `cS{{` and get the same effect.

It’s possible the splitjoin plugin can do something similar.